# Length of array use for SQLite IN clause

Tags: sqlite

For a query

```
SELECT * FROM plain_note WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, ...);
```

For the filter id array, I was wondering, is there any limitation on the input array length?

Let's say the size of array is 10,000 items, as fast as speed performance is concerned, is it better to perform using `IN` clause, or is it better to perform a multiple query like

```
SELECT * FROM plain_note WHERE id = 1;
SELECT * FROM plain_note WHERE id = 2;
SELECT * FROM plain_note WHERE id = 3;
SELECT * FROM plain_note WHERE id = ...;
```

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find anything in the documentation on `WHERE IN (...)`, but the length of a SQLite statement itself [has a max limit](https://sqlite.org/limits.html).

However, to your second question, the `WHERE id IN (1, 2, 3, ...)` version is far preferable to doing separate queries for each `id` value, for so many reasons.  The biggest reason is that the former `WHERE IN` approach requires making only one rountrip to and from SQLite.  Note that your first version is identical to this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM plain_note WHERE id = 1 OR id = 2 OR id = 3 OR ...
```

Answer (score 0):

See:

- [Is there a limit for the number of items in an IN clause?](http://sqlite.1065341.n5.nabble.com/Is-there-a-limit-for-the-number-of-items-in-an-IN-clause-td81307.html)
- [Implementation Limits For SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html)

There seems to be no limit for number of parameters in the IN-clause, But the maximum length of the query might be limiting here.

Converting and executing the IN-clause as multiple SELECT statements is VERY SLOW!

An alternative would be to insert the parameters into a [temporary table](https://sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) and to query with

```
SELECT *
FROM plain_note
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM temp_table);
```